# How to make my search bar work

Tags: html

Here's the code for the site search of a site.

```
<div class="search-big">
    <div class="sb-close"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search-wrap">
            <div class="content-head text-center">
            <span>Music - Music - Music - Music</span>
            <h5>Discover and listen to your favorite tracks<br>High Quality Streaming</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="sb-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Artist / Track / Album / Podcast">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it to really search my site?

Comment: Here is a shoe, now tell me how to walk. Sorry, but your question is not really answerable. You need, at least, to give us some context. Do you use ASP, PHP, or ... ? Searching what? Etc.

Comment: This Html has nothing to do with search.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of of other things needs to be done.

1. Submit search keyword to the server(use AJAX if you want to use autocomplete feature)
2. Search database with the keyword in the server(use elastic search or similar for a full fledged searching framework).
3. Give response to the client.

Comment: Its a site where you could listen to music. The search bar exists, but when you type a keyword and search, it doesn't return any results. Its just static. I want the search bar to be able to search my whole site for whatever keyword a user inserts and give results. I've been told that for a search bar written in html to function, you need PHP to make it work. I'm not well versed in PHP so i'm in need of help or directives. Thanks

Comment: Of course we would need a database(place where music details stored) to search and in order to interact with the database we would need a server side scripting language(PHP is one of them).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to create a search function with HTML only. If you want it to be functional, you should use PHP for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at search engines like Solr and ElasticSearch and integrate it to your back-end system.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

https://www.elastic.co/

Html can't help you with that. The only thing you can do with HTML is to forward the content of your text field to some public search engines (for example google).
https://www.google.com/search?q=%s

Where %s is a string you want to search.